# HTML5 video pixel error in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, pixel

I'm having some trouble with HTML5 video in IE9.

Video (MP4) is playing, but it looks like there's an encoding error as it now and then jumps and display white squares, almost like oversized pixels, in parts of the image.

I don't have this problem on my machine, in my IE, but co-workers seem to have this problem. And we have the same version of IE installed.

I tried adding `codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"` to the code, but it did not solve the problem.

Anyone got an idea on what this might be?

Comment: IE9's use of the video element should be an embarrassment to Microsoft but I'm sure they are not as it struggles to handle any modern code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in the conversion process. I tried converting the files, same settings, but in a different converter, and this seemed to solve the problem. So if you have choppy, wierd video in IE, try converting it again. :)